# Compare two JSON by key return value which is not in second

Tags: php, json

I would like to compare two JSON by key **objectID** and return value(s) as an array which are not in first.json.

Example:

**first.json**:

```
[
   {
      "desc":"lorem ipsum",
      "name":"Red Apple",
      "objectID":"18093",
      "price":"0.00",
      "product_id":"18999"
   }
]
```

**second.json**

```
[
   {
      "desc":"lorem ipsum",
      "name":"Red Apple",
      "objectID":"18093",
      "price":"0.00",
      "product_id":"18999"
   },
   {
      "desc":"lorem ipsum",
      "name":"Yellow Banana",
      "objectID":"17410",
      "price":"30.00",
      "product_id":17410
   }
]
```

Because objectID 17410 is not in first.json I would like to return it as an array in the output:

```
$difference = ['17410']
```

It is somehow possible?

Comment: Fix both of your JSONs please.

Comment: Use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it into an object. Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to filter out all `product_id` values from your JSONs and get the difference with [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) (as a hint: try using array_diff both ways (meaing: `array_diff($json1, $json2)` and `array_diff($json2, $json1)`), youll see a small difference)

Comment: @Rafal I think I get it working, thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggestion by @Definitely not Rafal:

```
<?php 

$string = file_get_contents("/var/www/input1.json");
$records = json_decode($string, true);
$objId = array_column($records, 'objectID');

print_r($objId);

$string2 = file_get_contents("/var/www/input2.json");
$records2 = json_decode($string2, true);
$objId2 = array_column($records2, 'objectID');

echo "<br>";
print_r($objId2);

echo "<br>";
var_dump(array_diff($objId2, $objId));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pursue the following way to meet the requirements:

```
let a = (x,y) => {
let z = []
x.forEach(x1 => {
    y.filter(y1 => {
        if(x1.objectID != y1.objectID){
            
          z.push(y1.objectID);  
        }
    })
}); return z;
```

}

```
a(arr1,arr2);
```

Hope it answers your query.